# Problem with Drupal 7.0 installation - PHP extensions disabled

Tags: installation, installer, cms, drupal

when I install **Drupal** I have the following problem.

> PHP extensions           Disabled
>  Drupal
>   requires you to enable the PHP
>   extensions in the following list (see
>   the [system requirements page](http://drupal.org/requirements) for more
>   information):
>
> gd

I tried to solve it according to this [page](http://drupal.org/node/1073232) but with no success.

Have you encountered the same problem and solved it?

I'm using Linux (Ubuntu)

thank you for help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you don't have the GD extension installed.  I don't use Ubuntu any longer, but I think it may be named php5-gd, so you'd need to install that package and restart your webserver and it should then work.

Answer (score 6):

1. Install the gd package:

   ```
   apt-get install php5-gd php-db php5-mysql
   ```
2. Restart the web server:

   ```
   sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
   ```

That should do it.